# Good WPF apps for creating CodedUI tutorials

Tags: .net, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I want to create some small tutorials about CodedUI tests and I need some desktop apps that have a were created with the help of WPF.

Of cause I could create my own sample app, but i wanted to use a real world application for this.

Answer (score 1):

Look on [www.codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com).

There are plenty of open source WPF apps available.

If you want to test one of mine personally, check out [MTGenome](http://mtgenome.codeplex.com).  I could even add you to the project if you would like to add tests to it.  We are using Caliburn and MVVM, so it should be pretty testable.

Comment: Thanks I've check out. Nice game. It would be great if it was finished

Comment: You may want to svn and build the latest revision as the previous release is quite old.

Comment: I am trying to get enough interest to get working on it again.  We are in need of more team members.